# Does Wordpress have any wrapper classes for $_POST, $_GET and $_REQUEST?

Tags: php, wordpress, post, get, request

There are many frameworks that will provide a helper object for dealing with these variables i.e. symfony has a `sfRequest` object that has a member function `getParameter(`) that can get used to get `$_POST` and `$_GET` variables.

I'm wondering if Wordpress has something similar to this? I've seen [this solution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37682/passing-post-data-from-one-wp-post-to-another) that seems to append the new variables to the `query_vars` action, however some articles mention it will only work with GET. I was unable to get this to work with a form using both `$_POST` and `$_GET` myself, and certainly wouldn't think this is ideal to use if you have many variables that can be passed this way.

Is using plain old $_REQUEST, $_POST and $_GET the standard way to do work with request variables in Wordpress? Or is there a better way (specifically using the functions provided by Wordpress, rather than other libraries) to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing I could find was the [HTTP API](http://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API), but that's only for *sending* requests.  There's no wrapper class for dealing with such superglobals that's specific to WordPress.

Comment: Interesting - I've been googling like crazy for this expecting to find some WP class that was just really well hidden or something but I definitely have to agree at this point - thank you for confirming this for me!